# A content provider to replace ContactcsContract

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

Im trying to make some changes to an app that i've downloaded, the app uses ContactContracts to show the list of contacts stored in the phone,

what im trying to do is using a content provider to show a list of contacts that i've stored in my database

the original app uses this method to load contacts from the phone and store the in "contact" object:

```
public void loadContactsData(){
    if(SmsSchedulerApplication.contactsList.size()==0){
        System.currentTimeMillis();

        String[] projection = new String[] {Groups._ID};
        Uri groupsUri =  ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI;
        groupCursor = managedQuery(groupsUri, projection, null, null, null);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
              if(!(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)).equals("0"))){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                if(phones.moveToFirst()){
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.content_uri_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    contact.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    contact.number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));

                    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contact.content_uri_id, null, null);
                    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                        do{

                            if(!String.valueOf(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID))).equals(contact.number) && cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID))!=0){
                                boolean isValid = false;
                                if(groupCursor.moveToFirst()){
                                    do{
                                        if(!cur.isClosed() && !groupCursor.isClosed() && cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID)) == groupCursor.getLong(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Groups._ID))){
                                            isValid = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }while(groupCursor.moveToNext());
                                }
                                if(isValid){
                                    contact.groupRowId.add(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID)));
                                }
                            }
                        }while(cur.moveToNext());
                    }
                    cur.close();
                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contact.content_uri_id));
                    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
                    try{
                        contact.image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        contact.image.getHeight();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e){
                        contact.image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.no_image_thumbnail);
                    }

                    SmsSchedulerApplication.contactsList.add(contact);
                }
              }
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

im not familiar with using content provider so im not sure what should i define in my content provider class

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a content provider if you don't want to. Also using a contacts provider example to realize an own user database management is the wrong approach here. The provider was evolved multiple times to support all kind of use cases. I mean, just look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) of it. All this tables and and micromanagement. I doubt that you need all of this.

I suggest you do the following. First create you database scheme. Find out what tables do you need and what columns are required for the application to work. Then put it into an [sqlite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and define the queries to store and retrieve the contents. This should be all necessary to make the app work.

Then if everything works and you still have the motivation or requirements, create a [content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html?) by using the existing database as the data store withing the provider and declaring URI's to access and modify the content. Of course you then have to rewrite some portions of the existing code. But if you were using the query, update, delete and insert methods of the database, it should be no problem.

Or you do it the hard way and insert your contacts in the contacts provider by inserting raw contacts. But it you don't have to share your contacts with the system (to crate custom actions on existing contacts for example) or other apps, then just don't do it.